# Best RAID Configuration for HyperV VM

Tags: windows, raid, hyper-v

I plan to make an HyperV server with 5 or 6 vms,
here is the hardware :

```
Xeon L3426 4core 8 thread
16 go ram
2*2To HDD
Dell H200 Raid Controller (RAID 0 OR 1);
```

and VMs contains that :

```
4 vms are windows server 2008 r2 
1 : font end TMG 2010, 
2 : AD DC, 
3 : SHarepoint 2010 +  SQL SEVER 2008 (analyse, report , integration),
4 : TFS 2010
```

2 vms are debian (apache + tomcat + mysql)

i want to know whats the best raid mode to have better access performance

```
1) HARD RAID 0;
2) HARD RAID 1;
3) SOFT RAID 0 on 50% of each HDD
4) NO RAID But i would put 3 vms on each HDD (backup on the other disk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your options;

1. Hardware R0 - could be faster but if you lose a disk you lose all your data.
2. Hardware R1 - plenty fast enough but you can lose either disk and carry on just fine, replacing the lost disk later for full resilience.
3. Software 0 - just as risky as hardware R0 but with added CPU and IO overhead.
4. No RAID - no less risky that hardware R1 but more complex and with no auto-failover mechanism built in.

Go with option 2) Hardware RAID 1, no question, it's the only way.

Comment: why that ? security ? but if i mirror backup with 2 disk ? (no raid).... with separate disk can i get better performance than 1 raid 1 ?

Comment: No, I've added some extra detail, see above.

Comment: ok thanks , i'll follow your advice, until i got 4 disk